How can know Who create instance?
I have two classes: A and B. The B type holds a reference to an instance of class A as a private field.
public class A
{
    List<T> list;

    public A ()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public object GetCreatedInstance()
    {
        // get who create instance
    }
}

public class B
{
    A a;
    public B()
    {
        a = new A();
    }
}

How can know type who created A class ?

This sounds like an XY Problem. Please explain what you are trying to achieve, ultimately.

Not sure that I understood the question correctly, but...
you call "a = new A()" inside B-class constructor, so it is class B creating class A instance.
Also if you have many other classes, which instantiate class A, then you just can add those references inside A-class constructor and record it into a new variable.

Although Arda-Çetinkaya's solution seems appropriate, I agree with Sweeper that I would first like to understand what problem you are trying to solve. So far, the question looks like this: I have a microscope, I need to drive a nail, how do I do that? And while it is physically possible to drive a nail with a microscope, there are other alternatives: find a hammer, etc.

Not sure if [CallerMemberName] works in ctors and if so, would work for you?

You can achieve this by using StackTrace class in C#, this will give you access to caller type.
 using System.Diagnostics;

public class A <T> where T : class
{
    List<T> list;

    public A ()
    {
        list = new List<T>();
    }

    public object GetCreatedInstance()
    {
         StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
         StackFrame frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1); 
         var method = frame.GetMethod();
         return method?.DeclaringType;
    }
}

And you can use it from other class:
public class B
{
    A<string> a;
    public B()
    {
        a = new A<string>();
        Console.WriteLine($"A was created by: {a.GetCreatedInstance()}");
    }
}

when you run the app you will see it has been called by B
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        B b = new B();
    }
}

Here is the working dotnet fiddle for this answer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6NjwaC

shouldn't you be calling GetCreatedInstance in the constructor and saving the info in a field?

Doesn't matter, the idea hear is to show the usage of StackTrace class to obtain caller type.. this just kinda pseudo impl.

It very much depends on what you mean by "who created the instance". Is it the name of the logged-in user, a class, method or property name or is it a class instance or something else?
Assuming that you mean a class instance, I suggest adding a Parent property to the A class (I called it Parent, but you could also call it Creator or Owner):
public class A
{
    private readonly List<T> list = new();

    public A (B parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;
    }

    public B Parent { get; }
}

public class B
{
    A a;

    public B()
    {
        a = new A(this);
    }
}

Now, a.Parent is the creator of a.
The code of A can be simplified by using a primary constructor:
public class A(B parent)
{
    private readonly List<T> list = new();

    public B Parent { get; } = parent;
}

If different classes can instantiate A, then you would have to change the type of Parent to a common ancestor or interface. If there is no relation between the creators, this would be object.

Seems like a premature solution to x in a y problem to me.
